# How to simply use keras in a distributed config by wrapping it in estimator

Tags: tensorflow, keras, distributed

I had some experiments with a keras model, and just want to run it in a distributed configuration. Based on the code that I see in different web sources, I ended up with below simple script:

```
cluster = {'ps': ['system1:port1'], 'worker': ['system2:port2','system3:port3']}
task = {'type': 'worker', 'index': 0}
os.environ['TF_CONFIG'] = json.dumps({'cluster': cluster, 'task': task})

def main(_):
  job_name = task['type']
  task_index = task['index']
  if job_name == "ps":
      cluster_spec = tf.train.ClusterSpec(cluster)
      server = tf.train.Server(cluster_spec, job_name=job_name, task_index=task_index)
      server.join()
  else:
    with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(
        worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d" % task_index, cluster=cluster)):
        model_dir = <a shared directory for all worker machines>

        # Define a Keras Model.
        model = tf.keras.Sequential()
        model.add(...)

        # Compile the model.
        optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.2)
        model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
        model.summary()

        config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(
            experimental_distribute=tf.contrib.distribute.DistributeConfig(
                train_distribute=tf.contrib.distribute.CollectiveAllReduceStrategy(),
                eval_distribute=tf.contrib.distribute.CollectiveAllReduceStrategy())
        )
        keras_estimator = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(
            keras_model=model, config=config, model_dir=model_dir)

        tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(
            keras_estimator,
            train_spec=tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=input_fn_train, steps=100),
            eval_spec=tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=input_fn_test))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I run 3 copies of this code on 3 different machines by adjusting the task variable in the second line. I am running tensorflow v1.12.2 and prefer to keep this version. The cluster computers are able to find each other and it is set up with no error. I have the functions `input_fn_train` and `input_fn_test` also defined in my original script, which return tensorflow datasets at their output. But I have some questions:

1- Do I need a cheif task to be specified explicitly?

2- What I want to do is to do distributed learning on machines with or without GPUs, so one machine may have only CPU and another one have both CPU and GPU. At the moment, it doesn't matter to me how to allocate the devices and just want to run multiple copies of my model to do data parallelism. Are the mentioned strategies correct? If not, which distribution strategy should I use?

3- Is the code correct and complete? (after adding input functions and import clauses, of course). Do I need to add something else such as strategy scope?

4- With keras model I was able to get the model training history after running model.fit() and easily and do whatever I want. Here with estimators it seems that I should do it through Tensorboard, which I am not familiar. Is there any other simple way to get the training and evaluation data in a distributed setting?

5- I was able to easily set early stopping or best model saving callbacks in keras previously. How can I add them to the above distributed setting with minimal code change?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to take a look at this package

https://github.com/maxpumperla/elephas.

This provides a highly sophisticated layer of distributed deep learning. If needed, you can fork and modify with the due credits to the developers.

Comment: Thank you very much! Will have a look at it.

Comment: if you find this answer useful feel free to upvote and mark this answer as accepted answer. thanks. happy learning :)